# howdoi Failed to establish a network connection howdoi

Tags: python-3.x

i install howdoi success. but i take 'howdoi java date ' ,it point 'Failed to establish a network connection' in the console.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzUFN.png)

Comment: with python3.61.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"C:\Program Files\python\Lib\site-packages\howdoi"  python.py  '     http: //www. google.com/search?q=site:{0}%20{1}' i can't connect.but i can connect "http: //www.google.com.hk/search?q=site:{0}%20{1}",So I changed it here. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BC0a.png)